# Find the smallest A(a inequality problem in calculus)

Tags: calculus

Q : Let $f(x)=5x^2+Ax^{-5}$ for $x>0 $, where A is a positive constant. Find the smallest A such that $f(x)\geq28  , \forall{x}>0$

my solution so far.

Let $g(x)=5x^2+Ax^{-5}-28$

FOC : $g'(x)=10x-5Ax^{-6}=0$ $\Rightarrow x^7=A/2 \Leftrightarrow x=(\frac{A}{2})^{\frac{1}{7}}$

SOC : $g''(x)=10+30Ax^{-7}>0,$ since $A>0, x>0$ strictly concave up.

so g(x) has a minimum  at $x=(\frac{A}{2})^{\frac{1}{7}}$ for x>0

plug in $x=(\frac{A}{2})^{\frac{1}{7}}$ to $g(x)\geq0$.

But the real problme is : "how can I solve this equation and get a smallest A?"

I'm stuck with this very step and I need a hint to proceed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have already got that $g$ reaches its minimum when $x = \sqrt[7]{\frac{A}2}$, and so we need to ensure $g\left(\sqrt[7]{\frac{A}2}\right) = 0$ to get the smallest $A$.  Thus we solve:

$$5\sqrt[7]{\frac{A^2}4}+A\sqrt[7]{\frac{32}{A^5}} = 28 \iff A^{2/7} = \frac{28}{\frac5{\sqrt[7]{4}}+\sqrt[7]{32}} = 4 \sqrt[7]4 \iff A = 256$$